# PHPMailer how to add embedded image inside foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, phpmailer

PHPmailer will not let me add an embedded image inside a foreach loop the path is correct but for some reason it is not adding the image i have checked other sorces on here but with no luck the images are embedding fine when out of the loop but it is just when i call them by using variable names eg the way i need to inside a for each loop as the images will be dynamic it will not embed any help appreciated.

The path looks all good but it just will not run in the loop?
Please let me know if you need to see any more code i just did not want to include irrelevant code as i know the message is already sending fine it is just this bit that i have a problem with. I have the table working in html that is not being sent via email if that is of any use outputting the images correctly in the foreach loop

```
<tbody>'.
    '<span style="display:none">'. $i = 1;' .</span>'.

         $total_quantity_count = 0;
         $grand_total = 0;

    foreach($items_purchased_array as $item){
       if (!$mail->addEmbeddedImage(getcwd() . '/' . $item['image'],'product_pic'.$i)) {
       echo 'Failed to attach '. getcwd() . '/' . $item['image'],'product_pic'.$i;
    }

      </tbody>
```

Comment: this maybe a silly question but are you sure (a) You have items to loop through

Comment: @OrlandoP. yes it definitly is looping through the items i have the same form and it outputs the data and  i a have also i have checked the path with the echo Failed to attach  '. getcwd(). /. item['image'] and it outputs the file i want to attach. but i will just will not embed ill double check again for errors but all seems to be ok with my code which is why i don't understand why it will not let me embed the images

Comment: @OrlandoP. i have found the bug for some reason it was adding a space after the $item['image'], 'product_pic'.$i; i was able to fix it by using the trim function on $item['image] thanks for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 0):

Here was what i did to fix this

```
  if (!$mail->addEmbeddedImage(getcwd().'/'.trim($item['image']),trim('product_pic'.$i))){
                    echo 'Failed to attach '.getcwd().'/'.$item['image'],('product_pic'.$i);
```